# YOAST plugin does not work any longer in redirecting images

Tags: wordpress, facebook, graph, yoast

Since september 12th (this is an estimate) I cannot upload an image in YOAST and have it redirect when uploading the image to facebook. I have checked the changelogs of both YOAST and the graph API of Facebook, but cannot find anything note worthy in their changelogs. I did notice both of them had updates (facebook 12th of september and YOAST 19th of september). I have not changed any settings and according to the YOAST API the settings should be correct. I have searched the internet and have found nothing of use and I cannot reproduce a minimal code snippet for you since it's all plugin(s) and and the data is sensitive. This question is therefore mostly a question to determine whether anyone else has encountered this recently and/or has found a solution.

So basically whenever I upload an image on facebook which should redirect to my blog post, it remains an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, which was very vague and hard to find. You have to pay for YOAST premium to obtain this feature now. It used to be free, but not any longer.